# "circular" mean in R

Tags: r, time-series, average, mean

Given a dataset of months, how do I calculate the "average" month, taking into account that months are circular?

```
months = c(1,1,1,2,3,5,7,9,11,12,12,12)
mean(months)
## [1] 6.333333
```

In this dummy example, the mean should be in January or December.  I see that there are packages for circular statistics, but I'm not sure whether they suit my needs here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think

```
months <- c(1,1,1,2,3,5,7,9,11,12,12,12)
library("CircStats")
```

Now convert from months to radians, compute the circular mean, and convert back to months.  I'm subtracting 1 here assuming that January is at "0 radians"/12 o'clock ...

```
conv <- 2*pi/12 ## months -> radians
(res1 <- circ.mean(conv*(months-1))/conv)
```

The result is -0.3457.  You might want:

```
(res1 + 12) %% 12
```

which gives 11.65, i.e. partway through December (since we are still on the 0=January, 11=December scale)

I *think* this is right but haven't checked it too carefully.

For what it's worth, the `CircStats::circ.mean` function is very simple -- it might not be worth the overhead of loading the package if this is all you need:

```
function (x) 
{
    sinr <- sum(sin(x))
    cosr <- sum(cos(x))
    circmean <- atan2(sinr, cosr)
    circmean
}
```

Incorporating @A.Webb's clever alternative from the comments:

```
 m <- mean(exp(conv*(months-1)*1i))
 12+Arg(m)/conv%%12  ## 'direction', i.e. average month
 Mod(m)              ## 'intensity'
```

Comment: `12+Arg(mean(exp(conv*(months-1)*1i)))/conv%%12`, equivalently

Comment: That's a clever formula. I wonder if that equation can be used for determining means for bimodal data?

Comment: In the wiki article about this subject it is written " The resulting radius will be 1 if all angles are equal. If the angles are uniformly distributed on the circle, then the resulting radius will be 0, and there is no circular mean." How do we calculate the 'radius' to use that as an indicator of the strength of the mean? Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities

Comment: @Chris Just `Mod` instead of `Arg`: `Mod(mean(exp(conv*(months-1)*1i)))`

Comment: Http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Mod included some links